# prefix or postfix operation on c pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
void increment(int *p) {
*p = *p + 1;
}
void main() {
int a = 1;
increment(&a);
printf("%d", a);
}
```

for above if I run above code it prints 2
but if I replace `*p = *p + 1;` with `*p++;`
it is printing 1.Why is it so?...

Comment: 1) Don't spam tags. 2) Because they are different statements.

Comment: If you find it difficult to differentiate between `(*p)++` and `*(p++)` without the parenthesis, **always** use the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

[operator precedence...](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

When writing `*p++` you get these operations:

1. `p++` is evaluated (later p will get incremented)
2. the original value of `p` is returned (since this is a suffix `++`, if it was prefix, the value returned would have been p+1... )
3. dereference of the the pointer `p` and since `p` earlier pointed to `1`, that's what you get

Comment: That's incorrect. The dereference will happen before the increment, so you'll get the value at `*p` *then* increment `p`.

Comment: @Quentin you're right. sorry. going to delete, but just for clarification - doesn't the link I shown says that ++ takes precedence?

Comment: @Quentin Shouldn't it be, (1) `p++` is evaluated, (2) the original value of pointer is returned, (3) dereference on the original pointer; ?

Comment: @songyuanyao yes, that's all "getting the value at `*p`". Then the side-effect of `++` kicks in.

Comment: @CIsForCookies operator precedence rules are there to resolve syntactic ambiguities. They don't affect order of evaluation at all, that's another set of rules.

Comment: @Quentin Fine, that matches what I unserstand. "The dereference will happen before the increment" just seems not accurate and leading to misunderstanding..

Comment: I tried to edit according to you comments just to see if I understood correctly

Comment: @songyuanyao well that's exactly what happens, so I'm not sure what you feel is misleading about it.

Comment: @CIsForCookies sounds a bit convoluted, but that's it, yes.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, from the aspect of result it's true; I meant technically the deference, i.e. the evaluation of `operator*` is performed at last.

Comment: @songyuanyao it is the outermost operator (i.e. `*p++` is parsed as something like `deref(post_incr(p))`) and dictates the result of the whole expression. However, its action is performed *before* the side-effect of `++` is applied (that's the property of `++`).

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [precedence table for operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) you will see that the postfix increment has a higher precedence than dereference. This means that `*p++` will actually be grouped as `*(p++)`.

You should use parenthesis to explicit what you are trying to do, in this case `(*p)++` or `++(*p)`.

Comment: `++(*p)` doesn't need the parentheses, as it's unambiguous.

Comment: @Quentin: Indeed, but I find it easier to read because with `++*p` you could miss the `*`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question consult the [table of C operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence): operator `+` has lower precedence than dereference operator `*`, while increment operator `++` has higher precedence.

That is why `++` is applied to the pointer, while `+ 1` is applied to the result of pointer dereference.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). Check what happens when you do `(*p)++`.

Note: You may also try doing `*(p++)`. But this will invoke *undefined behaviour* [UB](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

Answer (score -1):

In the first case `*p=*p+1;` the control adds one to the value at `*p` by 1 and then stores the result in `*p`. This actually uses a temporary variable during program runtime which you are not able to see. Now,the value at the temporary instance is incremented and finally stored in `*p`.
In the second case, `*p++;` a sequence point concept comes.

According to C standard an object's stored value can be modified only once (by evaluation of expressions) between two sequence points.
A sequence point occurs:

- at the end of full expressions
- at the &&,|| and ?: operators.
- at a function call (after evaluation of arguments,just before the actual call)

In `*p++;`, since the expression is modified only after the sequence point is encountered, `*p` is unable to store the modified value of itself.